# kendo.toString() for date on MVVM bind

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a string date value of 3/2/2013 when using the Kendo DatePicker and Date(-62135578800000) from the when encoded to the array.  I am binding a Kendo array to a template and would like the date to be user friendly, like "Sat, Mar 2".  I have tried toString and ParseDate with no luck.  I created a fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/srakestraw/Q3MF8/, but can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

When I load the page, I get a date values like Date(-62135578800000) using Json.Encode, see below.

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
                slots: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Slots))
              });
```

On the front-end, the user selects a date using the KendoUI datepicker and I push the value the the array.  Am I using the wrong date format?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Date(-62135578800000)` is not a valid JavaScript Date object:

`alert(typeof Date(-62135578800000)); // string`

Here is the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q3MF8/3/

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the parsedate.

Comment: @AtanasKorchev, negative timestamps represent dates before January 1st, 1970. Seems that you are younger that Unix ;-)

Comment: @OnaBai well I may be younger than the Unix epoch but Date(-62135578800000) is not a valid JavaScript date. Try it: var d = Date(-62135578800000);
alert(d); // shows now.

Comment: Try `var d = new Date(-62135578800000); alert(d);` check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/3SnPn/ Maybe it is not valid but my browsers (chrome/firefox/safari) do it pretty well...

Comment: @AtanasKorchev, Please, check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date, it says: _The JavaScript Date object range is -100,000,000 days to 100,000,000 days relative to 01 January, 1970 UTC._ So that value is in the range.

Comment: That's the difference between using `Date()` that is a (native) function and `new Date()` that is the constructor of `Date` JavaScript object.

Comment: @OnaBai I don't understand your point. Here is a quote from the documentation that you linked: Invoking JavaScript Date in a non-constructor context (i.e., without the new operator) will return a string representing the current time.

Which is exactly what I said. Yes, timestaps can be negative. I will edit my answer.

Comment: My point was that timestamps can be negative. What is not valid is passing a negative number to `Date` function (while it is valid argumentfor `Date` constructor).

Answer (score 0):

This will format dates in a manner you can work with (ISO 8601) instead of those hideous Json.Encode formatter monstrosities.

```
@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))
```